# Web interface with image pane able to click for coordinates AND zoom and pan.

Tags: javascript, java, click, zooming

I would like to add an image to a GUI on a web page that allows the user to zoom and pan (or zoom and scroll) and also click the image to retrieve real coordinates that can be used by the back end system to process the image.

I've found a number of JavaScript libraries for smooth zoom and pan, and a few examples of clicking an image and using the coordinates. However, I've not found a good example of combining the them. It seems like there should be a tried and true solution to this somewhere. It is of course a little complicated because you have to scale the coordinates with the image. I don't require smooth zoom -- increments of scale are fine.

Some additional information: I'm actually converting a Java desktop program to a web based program, likely on Spring framework. The back end will use the Java methods I've already created. The purpose of the program is to allow a pathologist to inspect microscope slide images and indicate regions of those images and then process them.

I'm open to all good ideas for constructing the web interface, so whatever the best way to do this is, I'll take it. I've mostly been looking at jQuery.

Comment: As for image zoom and pan, you have plenty options indeed (zoomify, openseadragon…). With additional coordinates requirement, mapping libraries like Leaflet and OpenLayers could be more suited, even though all should have a way to handle it somehow.

Comment: Thanks ghybs. openseadragon looks like it might be just the thing by itself.